# Disabling Autorun For Multiple Remote Desktop Connections On Windows Server 2008?

Tags: remote-desktop, boot, windows-server-2008, autorun

I have a few programs that run at startup.

But it becomes very annoying when another client enters to the session with Remote Desktop Connection. The server starts to run the same processes. This is a huge waste of resources and results incompatibilities.

How to prevent that? I want to make the server run those processes once, not twice.